# Setting an Array Element as an Object Property

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to set an array element as an object Property

Simplified example:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = { array[1]: 'good' }
```

Above causes an error.

**Update:** In fact, I am passing the object as a part of another array ie a simplified example would be:

```
aObj[value] = ['one', {array[1]: 'good'}, 'two', 'three', 'four'];
```

Setting the `obj[array[1]] = 'good';` style would mean using

```
aObj[value][1][array[1]] = 'good';
```

Comment: "*Of course I can declare the array element as a variable*". No, you can't, unless you use computed property names, introduced by ECMAScript 6. Your second code will produce the key `"arr"`, not `"b"`.

Comment: @Oriol .. You are right... thank you ... I updated & corrected my post :)

Comment: Goodness, that data structure is mighty confusing

Answer (score 8):

`{ array[1]: 'good' }` throws an error because, when you use the Object literal notation in JavaScript, it treats the string before `:` as the identifier and a valid identifier name cannot have `[` or `]` in it.

So, use the `[]` notation, which allows any string to be used as the property name, like this

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = {};
obj[array[1]] = 'good';
```

Comment: Also it cannot be a variable before the `:`

Comment: Seems in ES6 you may have an expression before the `:` as mentioned by  @dfsq

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's time to start giving ES6 answers too. In ECMAScript6 you can use expressions as object keys:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var obj = {
    [array[1]]: 'good'
}
```

In fact, this syntax is already supported in Firefox.

Currently the only way to use variable is to use bracket notation as described in other answer.

Comment: Thank you dfsq. I updated my post with more info. I am actually coding scripts for Firefox, However, to be more compatible, I stay with ES5 for the time being. ;) Good to know though for when I am coding a Firefox addon.

Comment: I then stand partially corrected :)

Comment: In ES5, you can do: `Object.defineProperty({},array[1],{value:'good',enumerable:true})`. That might not be considered an improvement.